# Electron recovery after crash on render process

Tags: electron, crash-recovery

I'm building an electron app that must reload the render process window if a crash happens.

Currently I can restart the app from the main process

```
app.relaunch();
app.quit();
```

But I cannot detect the window crashing.
I tried using the

```
win.on('unresponsive', () => { ... } );
```

But the event is not getting generated when I crash the process.

To crash the process I tried:

- invoking the `process.crash()`
- using all the available memory.

Both ways successfully crash the process but again, I cannot find a way to detect it.

I tried also using, from the render process, the `window.onerror(...)` and sending via IPC to the main process a message when the crash is detected, but this seems not to work as well.

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out on this?  I have the same issue - render process occasionally crashes and it would be really nice to just reload automatically or take other appropriate action.

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking for the 'crashed' event in webContents. Check https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-crashed

For example put something like this in main process:

```
win.webContents.on('crashed', (e) => {
    app.relaunch();
    app.quit()
});
```

Comment: This makes sense to listen to `crashed` on webContents, but this still does not work, at least if you're manually calling `process.crash()` in the window.

Answer (score 0):

maybe look into "**pm2-windows-service**" which can install your app as windows service and watch if it crashes, to restart it

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-service

also electron has app.**setLoginItemSettings({ openAtLogin: true });** but that does not guard for crash, only provide automatic app start at windows login